# Why is the construction of std::optional<int> more expensive than a std::pair<int, bool>?

Tags: c++, performance, assembly, x86-64, c++17

Consider these two approaches that can represent an "optional `int`":

```
using std_optional_int = std::optional<int>;
using my_optional_int = std::pair<int, bool>;
```

Given these two functions...

```
auto get_std_optional_int() -> std_optional_int 
{
    return {42};
}

auto get_my_optional() -> my_optional_int 
{
    return {42, true};
}
```

...both **g++ trunk** and **clang++ trunk** *(with `-std=c++17 -Ofast -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti`)* produce the following assembly:

```
get_std_optional_int():
        mov     rax, rdi
        mov     DWORD PTR [rdi], 42
        mov     BYTE PTR [rdi+4], 1
        ret

get_my_optional():
        movabs  rax, 4294967338 // == 0x 0000 0001 0000 002a
        ret
```

[**live example on godbolt.org**](https://godbolt.org/g/XWkbhn)

---

**Why does `get_std_optional_int()` require three `mov` instructions, while `get_my_optional()` only needs a single `movabs`?** Is this a QoI issue, or is there something in `std::optional`'s specification preventing this optimization?

Also please note that users of the functions might be completely optimized out regardless:

```
volatile int a = 0;
volatile int b = 0;

int main()
{
    a = get_std_optional_int().value();
    b = get_my_optional().first;
}
```

...results in:

```
main:
        mov     DWORD PTR a[rip], 42
        xor     eax, eax
        mov     DWORD PTR b[rip], 42
        ret
```

Comment: `optional` is returned through a hidden pointer, meaning the type definition contains something prohibiting returning it through a register.

Comment: The obvious difference is that `std::pair` is an aggregate, while `std::optional` is not. Don't know if it should have an effect, but ya' know...

Comment: Doesn't `optional` have to allocate properly sized and aligned storage and then use placement new to actually construct the value?

Comment: Same problem with `boost::optional`, on any version of GCC, no fancy C++17 required for demo: https://godbolt.org/g/MV14mr

Comment: The aggregate vs non-aggregate typing, the SYS V x64 ABI and the fact that 4294967338 is 0x10000002a should make this clear.

Comment: Why does non-aggregates have to be returned on the stack?

Comment: You probably know that, but *strictly* speaking your "optional" isn't optional at all. Using a pair works with types like `int` but will have non-optional semantics with for example non-default-constructable types.

Comment: @PasserBy: It's not on the stack, it's through a hidden pointer (which could point wherever the caller wants it to point, e.g. into an existing object in memory).  I think the idea is that every instance of the object always has an address, because constructing the return-value object might embed pointers into it, so the callee needs to know that address.

Comment: I don't think it's the construction that's more expensive. I think it's returning it that's more expensive. If you try constructing it without returning it, you may see very different results.

Comment: Can you try folly::Optional<>? https://github.com/facebook/folly/blob/master/folly/Optional.h

Comment: @WojciechMigda `folly::Optional` doesn't have the necessary magic to make its special member functions conditionally trivial. (It also violates ODR by using the internal-linkage `None` in inline functions, and every single `constexpr` or `FOLLY_CPP14_CONSTEXPR` function is ill-formed NDR: you can't implement `optional`'s `constexpr` API with `aligned_storage`.) +1 for being `co_await`-able, but they'd be better off stealing the `optional` implementation from range-v3 and adding on the rest of their API.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

libstdc++ apparently does not implement [P0602 "variant and optional should propagate copy/move triviality"](https://wg21.link/p0602). You can verify this with:

```
static_assert(std::is_trivially_copyable_v<std::optional<int>>);
```

[which fails for libstdc++, and passes for libc++ and the MSVC standard library](https://godbolt.org/g/Yg4a44) (which really needs a proper name so we don't have to call it either "The MSVC implementation of the C++ standard library" or "The MSVC STL").

Of course MSVC *still* won't pass an `optional<int>` in a register because the MS ABI.

EDIT: This issue has been fixed in the GCC 8 release series.

Comment: `optional` still requires a destructor though, and that prevent from returning it in registers.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin it only needs a destructor when T has one.

Comment: Was that paper adopted? It's not reflected in the [latest draft](http://eel.is/c++draft/optional.ctor#6).

Comment: @Barry Per [this](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/) it's sitting in Library Evolution right now.

Comment: Correct, P0602 has not yet been adopted. The author made an attempt to communicate with the major implementors so that `optional` and `vector` could be "fixed" before people ship and lock in ABI. I believe libstdc++/libc++/MSFT `variant` all comply, as do libc++/MSFT `optional`, but apparently the libstdc++ `optional` maintainer did not get the memo.

Comment: P0602R4 was incorporated into the C++20 Working Draft in San Diego on 20181113.

Comment: Though the issue was fixed in GCC 8, it is present again in [trunk](https://godbolt.org/g/XWkbhn), GCC 10 and GCC 9

Answer (score 19):

> Why does `get_std_optional_int()` require three `mov` instructions, while
>   `get_my_optional()` only needs a single `movabs`?

The direct cause is that `optional` is returned through a hidden pointer while `pair` is returned in a register. Why is that, though? The SysV ABI specification, section *3.2.3 Parameter Passing* says:

> If a C++ object has either a non-trivial copy constructor or a
>   non-trivial destructor, it is passed by invisible reference.

Sorting out the C++ mess that is `optional` is not easy, but there seem to be a [non-trivial copy constructor at least in the `optional_base` class of the implementation I checked](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/optional#L338).

Comment: Doesn't have to be, but could be, and that's what counts for the compiler. So you actually have to look at the implementation.

Answer (score 15):

In [Calling conventions for different C++ compilers and operating systems by Agner Fog](http://www.agner.org/optimize/calling_conventions.pdf) it says that a copy constructor or destructor prevents from returning a structure in registers. This explains why `optional` is not returned in registers.

There has to be something else preventing the compiler from doing store merging (*merges contiguous stores of immediate values narrower than a word into fewer wider stores to reduce the number of instructions*)... **Update:** [gcc bug 82434 - -fstore-merging does not work reliably.](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=82434)

Comment: Any idea what this "something else" might be?

Comment: x86-64 does not have a `mov mem, imm64` so you can't merge the stores.

Comment: @Jester It could load `rax` with the merged value and store that into `[rdi]`.

Comment: It certainly could, but I don't think that has any inherent speed advantage and this is shorter machine code. It certainly doesn't reduce the number of instructions.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin the `get_std_optional_int():` returns pointer to the instance in `rax`, so if you would clobber it with immediate value, you would have to do another `mov rax,rdi` before `ret`.

Comment: It doesn't have to be `rax`, and it doesn't have to be "another". You could just do: `movabs  rax, 4294967338; mov [rdi], rax; mov rax, rdi; ret`.

Comment: @Maxim: gcc7 implemented store coalescing (which gcc3 or gcc4 broke, so gcc for *years* has sucked at adjacent narrow assignments), but there's still a missed optimization in objects with padding.  https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=82142.  (clang seems to have the same missed optimization in this case.)  gcc and clang will coalesce the stores if your write a function which stores through a `pair<int,int>` pointer: https://godbolt.org/g/44zodQ.

Comment: @Jester: gcc/clang actually *do* `movabs rax, 4294967338` / `mov     QWORD PTR [rdi], rax` if you store `{42,1}` into a `pair <int,int>` pointer.  See previous comment.  I agree this is questionable if you aren't bottlenecked on store throughput.

Comment: @PeterCordes It is not clear what exactly prevents store merging. [In this example just adding a destructor prevents it](https://godbolt.org/g/qzyufd).

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin: That's disappointing.  Probably because it's not trivially copyable.

Answer (score 3):

**The optimization is technically permitted**, even with `std::is_trivially_copyable_v<std::optional<int>>` being false.  However, it may require an unreasonable degree of "cleverness" for the compiler to find.  Also, for the specific case of using `std::optional` as the return type of a function, the optimization may need to be done at link-time rather than compile-time.

Performing this optimization would have no effect on any (well-defined) program's observable behavior,* and is therefore implicitly allowed under the [as-if rule](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15718279/1340389).  However, for reasons which are explained in other answers, the compiler has not been explicitly made aware of that fact and would need to infer it from scratch.  Behavioral static analysis is [inherently difficult](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice's_theorem), so the compiler may not be able to prove that this optimization is safe under all circumstances.

Assuming the compiler can find this optimization, it would then need to alter this function's calling convention (i.e. change how the function returns a given value), which normally needs to be done at link time because the calling convention affects all of the call sites.  Alternatively, the compiler could inline the function entirely, which may or may not be possible to do at compile time.  These steps would not be necessary with a trivially-copyable object, so in this sense the standard does inhibit and complicate the optimization.

`std::is_trivially_copyable_v<std::optional<int>>` ought to be true.  If it were true, it would be much easier for compilers to discover and perform this optimization.  So, to answer your question:

> Is this a QoI issue, or is there something in `std::optional`'s specification preventing this optimization?

It's both.  The spec makes the optimization substantially harder to find, and the implementation is not "smart" enough to find it under those constraints.

---

* Assuming you haven't done something really weird, like `#define int something_else`.

Comment: You're including the calling convention as part of "the implementation".  That's technically true, but unless you enable whole-program / link-time optimization, it's not something that compilers on a given platform will even try to change other than by fully inlining, or making constant-propagation cloned versions of functions.

Comment: I guess gcc could emit something like `.gcc_reg_return_get_std_optional_int.clone123` as well as a normal ABI-compliant definition.  Callers from other translation units couldn't assume this was present, though, so they'd have to call the regular version (unless you use LTO, in which case it would just inline because it's small).  But if the function was actually large, then sure cloning an alternate-calling-convention version of the function would be useful.  Probably most useful to return the parts in 2 separate regs, instead of packing into RAX.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Are you sure? The implementation of the *function* seems completely irrelevant here, only the implementation of `std::optional` should be necessary and since it is a template its implementation is always available.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: Yes, I'm confident that gcc and clang are following the C++ ABI they've decided to use, where **the criterion for packing into registers if small enough when returning or passing by value is `std::is_trivially_copyable_v<foo>`**.  You could maybe change the C++ ABI to implement more complicated rules for the case of template classes where the destructor exists but is known to optimize away, or something.  But this might require optimizations to be enabled always for compilers to agree with each other on how to pass certain objects.  (e.g. inline and optimize away.)

Comment: The C++ ABI is not intended to be stable the way the C ABI / calling convention is ([x86-64 System V psABI](https://github.com/hjl-tools/x86-psABI/wiki/X86-psABI)), but it does have to be possible for different compilers to reliably agree with each other.

Comment: @PeterCordes: I added a note about link-time, but I consider this a very minor detail, frankly.  Link-time optimization has been generally available for quite a while now, and I see little reason for most developers to turn it off.

Comment: The build scripts in most open source projects don't enable it (unfortunately), because it's not on by default and there's no portable command-line option to enable it the way `-O2` is portable across different compilers.  (Of course they should detect it along with other build-time detection, because it helps a lot).  But anyway, the code in the question is showing the ABI-compliant definition.  This is what you'd see if calling into a shared library or something, because LTO doesn't work across non-static library boundaries.

Comment: You might want to put more emphasis on this being the non-LTO version.  (Hmm, I'm curious now what gcc will do with LTO enabled, or with `static` inside a single TU.  I think `__attribute__((noinline))` is separate from `__attribute__((noclone))`, so it could still make a custom version.  I suspect it won't invent a custom more-convention calling convention, though)

Comment: I tried it (by adding some busy-work to the function so it won't inline on its own, and making it `static`).  gcc and clang stick to the normal calling convention, and don't even do constant-propagation from the constant return value. :/  https://godbolt.org/g/7sHCCt.  So yeah, that's a missed optimization.  (In clang's case, constant propagation for the return value fails even with `-stdlib=libc++`, which does implement `std::optional<>` that's trivially copyable and packs into a register.  Leading to a 10-byte `movabs` to create a mask to `test` the return value...)

Comment: Submitted https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=82432 re: the missed optimization, although that bug is more specifically about lack of constant propagation of constant return values from non-inline functions.

Comment: Turns out clang has constant propagation for `int` return values even without inlining.  But not for aggregates like `optional<int>`.  Submitted https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=34839 and https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=34840.